# I'm having trouble parsing the response of a SOAP service. What's wrong on the XML?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xml-parsing, xsd

I've tried a bunch of SOAP, XML, and xsd parsers including SAAJ and EasyWSDL among others, and none of them seem too work. I could parse this without a parser but I'll have to handle more complex responses too.

For some reason, the parsers return either a null document or an empty list of elements.
This is the response that I'm trying to parse:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:createDataResponse xmlns:ns1="http://3e.pl/ADInterface">
            <StandardResponse xmlns="http://3e.pl/ADInterface" IsError="true">
                <Error>Cannot save record in C_BPartner: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «c_bpartner_value»</Error>
            </StandardResponse>
        </ns1:createDataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: May be problem with quotes in "Cannot save record in C_BPartner: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «c_bpartner_value»" string?

Comment: DOM parsing seems to work, thanks M. M.

Comment: Alexey, I'll read more into that. Thanks.